# Consulta múltiples tablas con laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente diagrama:

[image: Diagrama]

Estoy haciendo la respectiva consulta para traer la información contenida en las tablas. Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
$data = Restaurant::leftJoin('restaurant_user', 'restaurants.id', 'restaurant_user.restaurant_id')
                    ->leftJoin('users', 'restaurant_user.user_id', 'users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('user_code_activation', 'users.id', 'user_code_activation.user_id')
                    ->leftJoin('codes', 'user_code_activation.code_id', 'codes.id')->get();
```

Dicho query me arroja la información correctamente, pero lo que no logro es conectar las seis tablas.

Ahora bien, alguna sugerencia por favor, para dicha consulta u otra alternativa idónea para realizarla.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es usar esa base de datos en un proyecto de Laravel, debes:

## 1. Definir los [Modelos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models) necesarios:

1. `User`
2. `Resturant`
3. `Code`

## 2. Definir las [relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) respectivas en cada modelo:

#### A. Para `User`:

1. `User` m--------m `Restaurant` **-->** `restaurants()`
2. `User` m--------m `Code` (user_activate_code) **-->** `activationCodes()`
3. `User` m--------m `Code` (user_redeem_code) **-->** `redeemCodes()`

#### B. Para `Resaturant`:

1. `Restaurant` m--------m `User` **-->** `users()`

#### C. Para `Code`:

1. `Code` m--------m `User` (user_activate_code) **-->** `activatedCodeUsers()`
2. `Code` m--------m `User` (user_redeem_code) **-->** `redeemCodeUsers()`

## 3. Hacer los querys con Eloquent:

Ya en este punto puedes usar el ORM de Laravel para hacer las consultas de manera simple, como:

```php
$restaurant = App\Restaurant::find(1); // traer un restaurante.
$restaurant->users(); // jalar los usuarios del restaurante.
```